# Largest number which leaves equal remainder with 3 given numbers

Tags: number-theory

N be the largest number that will divide 1315, 4675 and 6915, leaving the same remainder in each case. What is the 
remainder?

Comment: Hint: $N$ divides the differences of each two so also the gcd of these differences (and the gcd $= 1120$ already works, so it is the largest such $N)\ \ $

Comment: But can we say that the value of N that we get is the largest?

Comment: $N$ divides the gcd, so $N$ can't be larger than the gcd.

Comment: "will divide" is an unlucky formulation when we can have a remainder. You mean, when those numbers are divided by $N$ , the remainder will be the same, right ?